# What is samba equivalent for windows command "View user account details" NET USER [/DOMAIN]

Tags: samba

What is unix/samba equivalent for

windows command "View user account details from AD"

```
 NET USER /DOMAIN username
```

next unix command is not one

```
net -v -U username -S ad-server-host  RPC USER INFO username
```

it shows user group membership

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[wbinfo(1)](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/wbinfo.1.html) can query user account details, including group membership.

`wbinfo -i username` shows (brief) user info.  `wbinfo --user-domgroups` lists the user's group membership, but operates on SIDs rather than readable names.  Use additional `wbinfo` calls to convert between them:

```
wbinfo --user-domgroups $(wbinfo -n $USER) |
  while read g; do 
    wbinfo --sid-to-fullname "$g"
  done
```